# Add a class to header when url path changes in Laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

How can I add a class when I navigate to the individual blog pages.

For example when a user comes to the Home page the header color should be gold and when the user navigates to each and every single blogs the header background color should be red.

I have done it this way, where I need to add the `url path` to the header each and every time when I add a new blog page.

```
<div id="header" class="headertop {{ request()->is('blog','blog/test-one','blog/test-two','blog/test-three') ? 'blog-bg-red' : '' }}" >
<nav></nav>
</div>
```

Is there a way where i can add the class when the url passes `blog/` ?

Comment: Are there any other pages on the site? If so, what colour is the header for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request->is()` uses [Str::is()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-is) so you could just something like:

```
<div id="header" class="headertop {{ request()->is('blog', 'blog/*') ? 'blog-bg-red' : '' }}" >
    <nav></nav>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if it's only the index page that's gold and the rest are red, you could do:

```
<div id="header" class="headertop {{ request()->is('/') ? '' : 'blog-bg-red' }}" >
    <nav></nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better approach is passing a variable from the controller like below:

`return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');`

In the view you can check the value of the `{{ $name }}`.

This is much better I think since you don't need to depends on the url.